# matrix wise tangent inverse (arctan)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trigonometry, grassmannian

Given a matrix $X$, an expression for the matrix cosine and sine are given by
$$
\textrm{cos}(X) = \frac{e^{iX} + e^{-iX}}{2}\\
\textrm{sin}(X) = \frac{e^{iX} - e^{-iX}}{2i}
$$
I have been trying to find a convenient expression for the arctan with no luck. Is there any expression for the arctan?
$$
\textrm{tan}^{-1}(X) = \text{?}
$$

Comment: Find the power series for $tan^{-1}(x)$.

Comment: @Paul : Maybe you should expand on that a little bit and make it an answer. And write $\tan^{-1} x$ instead of $tan^{-1} x.$ Or else write $\arctan x$ $($not $arctan \, x). \qquad$

Answer (score 4):

Using Taylors formula (or term-by-term differentiation and geometric series), one can show that the Taylor series for $\tan^{-1}(x)$ or $\arctan(x)$ is the following

$$\arctan(x)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}x^{2k+1}=x-\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^5}{5}+\cdots,$$

which is absolutely convergent for $|x|<1$. This can be shown using the Ratio Test.

Using similar reasoning, we can identify a possible candidate for infinite series expansion of $\arctan(A)$ as

$$\arctan(A)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}A^{2k+1}=A-\frac{A^3}{3}+\frac{A^5}{5}+\cdots$$

However, we will also need to be very careful about when this series converges. It will converge if the matrix is small enough in the sense of the **matrix norm** being less than one $||A||<1$.

This results in a very nice situation if $A$ is a diagonalizable matrix, i.e., if $A=P^{-1}\Lambda P$ where $\Lambda=\left[\begin{array}{cccc}\lambda_1&0&\cdots&0\\0&\lambda_2&0\cdots&0\\
\vdots&0_\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
0&0&\cdots0&\lambda_n\end{array}\right]$, $P=[{\bf v}_1,...,{\bf v}_n]$, and $\lambda_k,{\bf v}_k$ is the eigenvalue/vector pair coming from diagonalization.

Specifically, consider the following sum. If we assume that $|\lambda_k|<1$ for each eigenvalue then the following computations are valid.

$$\begin{align*}
\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}A^{2k+1}&=A-\frac{A^3}{3}+\frac{A^5}{5}+...\\
&=P^{-1}\Lambda P-\frac{(P^{-1}\Lambda P)^3}{3}+\frac{(P^{-1}\Lambda P)^5}{5}+...\\
&=P^{-1}\Lambda P-\frac{(P^{-1}\Lambda^3 P)}{3}+\frac{(P^{-1}\Lambda^5 P)}{5}+...\\
&=P^{-1}(\Lambda-\frac{\Lambda^3}{3}+\frac{\Lambda^5}{5}+...)P\\
&=P^{-1}\left[\begin{array}{cccc}\arctan(\lambda_1)&0&\cdots&0\\0&\arctan(\lambda_2)&0\cdots&0\\
\vdots&0_\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
0&0&\cdots0&\arctan(\lambda_n)\end{array}\right]P
\end{align*}
$$

I hope this helps. Please let me know if you have any questions.